# USB not work after formatting with dd /dev/zero

Tags: linux, usb, formatting

About some time ago I formatted my 16GB usb drive with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc` on Ubuntu, but after that, USB drive completely stopped working. On Windows and Linux I get flash drive without any storage, on Mac I get nothing. Is there any way to make that flash drive work or it is hardware problem?

**UPDATE:**
This is only what I see on Mac:

```
Samuels-iMac:~ samueltulach$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType
USB:

    USB 3.0 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBXHCIPCI
      PCI Device ID: 0xa2af 
      PCI Revision ID: 0x0000 
      PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086 

        DataTraveler 2.0:

          Product ID: 0x6544
          Vendor ID: 0x0930  (Toshiba Corporation)
          Version: 1.00
          Serial Number: F7B694D9D729CEC118CA26BA
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: Kingston
          Location ID: 0x14b00000 / 2
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 200
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
          Built-In: Yes

    ...

Samuels-iMac:~ samueltulach$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *120.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SSD                     119.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HDD                     999.9 GB   disk1s2

Samuels-iMac:~ samueltulach$
```

Comment: Could you clarify "without any storage"?

Comment: @grawity Actually when I connect USB to PC, windows tell me that I must format that drive but when I click format there 0 bytes size to format. On Linux, when I open GParted there is no free space or partitions. (or it don't detect it) Wat?

Comment: That seems odd. If it was 16 GB before and you simply blanked it out, you should still get 16 GB of unpartitioned space afterwards. (Assuming it wasn't a cheap fake from China...)

Comment: @grawity Nope. Is was't fake. I was using it some time. Well. Probably some hardware problem. Ok. Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like you wiped out the MBR, and haven't reinstated it... though it's odd that the disk isn't being reported _at all_... have you used `fdisk` / GParted to try to re-create the MBR, and then create a new partition and filesystem?